# AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'read'

Tags: python

[image]

AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'read'

Comment: It's `pd.read_csv`.

Comment: Post code, don't post screenshots. Also, accept an answer and respond, don't just ask a question and then disappear.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo. Replace `pd.read.csv(...)` with [`pd.read_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).

You might have to set set the `'delimiter'` and other parameters.